# Why would social icon badges disappear after adding a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields

I hope I have worded this correctly because the issue may be a bit complex. After creating a quick links section with ACF and CPT UI, my social icons feature disappeared which were created with ACF disappeared from the home page, even though it is still on the home page in the wp dashboard.
[image]

[image]

The social icon badges should be above that copyright line and they are gone. If you look at footer.php:

```
<?php
/*
   Template Name: Home Page
*/
// Advanced Custom Fields
       $quick_links_title   = get_field('quick_links_title');

get_header(); ?>

   <?php get_template_part('content','hero'); ?>

   <?php get_template_part('content','donate'); ?>

      <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
               <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                     <h3 class="panel-title">Welcome to Three Green Birds!</h3>
                  </div><!-- panel-heading -->
                  <div class="panel-body">


                           <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

                           <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


                              <!--<div class="spacer"></div>-->
                            <div class="post-title">
                     <?php if (function_exists('get_cat_icon')) get_cat_icon('class=myicons'); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                              <div class="spacer"></div>
                              <div class="post-content">
                              <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); ?>
                              </div>
                              <div class="spacer"></div>
                                 <div class="postmeta"><span class="postcat"><b>Categories:</b> <?php the_category(', ') ?>
                                 <?php the_tags('| <b>Tags:</b> ', ', ', ''); ?>
                                 | <b>Comments:</b> <?php comments_popup_link('0', '1', '%', '', 'Off'); ?></span>
                               <span class="postcat"><?php edit_post_link('| <b>Edit</b>'); ?></span>
                                 </div>    
                              <div class="post-footer"></div>

                              <?php endwhile; ?>

                           <div class="navigation">
                           <br/><br/>
                              <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
                              <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
                           </div>

                        <?php else : ?>

                           <div class="post-title">Not Found</div>
                           <p class="post-content">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
                           <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/searchform.php"); ?>

                        <?php endif; ?>


                        <!-- Quick Links
                        ======================================================== -->
                        <section id="quick-links">
                           <div class="container">
                              <h2><?php echo $quick_links_title; ?></h2>
                              <div class="row">

                                 <?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'quick_links', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC')); ?>
                                 <?php while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                                 <div class="col-sm-3">

                                    <?php 

                                       if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                          the_post_thumbnail();
                                       }

                                    ?>

                                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
                                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                                 </div><!-- end col -->
                                 <?php endwhile; ?>

                              </div><!-- row -->
                           </div><!-- container -->
                        </section><!-- quick-links -->

                  </div><!-- panel-body -->
               </div><!-- panel panel-default -->
            </div><!-- col-md-8 -->
            <!-- SIDEBAR 
               ====================================================================== -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
               <?php if (is_active_sidebar('sidebar')) : ?>
                  <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar'); ?>
               <?php endif; ?>
            </div><!-- col-md-4 -->
         </div><!-- row -->
      </div><!-- container-fluid -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

It's all there, but why are they not visible in the browser. When I check the Chrome console, there is nothing inside of the div of col-lg-12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `wp_reset_postdata()` after running a loop on a secondary query.

Calling `$loop->the_post();` populates the global `$post` with the current post data in that loop. When you later call `get_field` without explicitly supplying a post ID, it gets the ID from `$post`, which is now the last post from your custom query instead of the home page.